# How to center div horizontally without display:table?

Tags: css, html, center

Is it possible to center a multiline `<div>` horizontally, while its contents remain aligned to the left (`text-align:left`), without specifying `display:table` and without having to know the pixel width of the `<div>` (it should become as wide as needed)? It has to work in Firefox 3 and Chrome.

I have the following working solution which contain  a `<div>` inside another `<div>`, so I'm only looking for a solution which doesn't need an inner `<div>`.

```
<style type="text/css">
div.showtitle {
  margin-left:auto;  
  margin-right:auto;
  display:table;
}
div.showtitle > div {
  background:#7777ff;
  color:ffffff;
  text-align:left;
  padding:.34em;
  font-size:140%;
}
</style>
<div class="showtitle"><div>Centered div<br>with left-aligned text</div></div>
```

FYI The reason why `display:table` and `font-size:140%` cannot be combined in the same `<div>` is that in Chrome it has a bad effect on the line height of the `font-size` of its container gets changed in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that it's impossible to do the center alignment without `display:table` or an inner `<div>` or specifying the width of the `<div>`.

Answer (score 2):

```
<div style="margin:0 auto; width:300px">
  Text<br />
  text
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to say that the pixel width of the `div` is not known in advance: it should become as wide as needed.

Answer (score 2):

All you should really need is to set a width on the `div` and set auto margins.  You don't need an outer `div`; the element will be horizontally centered in whatever block-level element it's contained in, including the body.

```
.showtitle 
{ 
    with: 350px; 
    margin-left: auto; 
    margin-right: auto; 
    text-align: left; 
}
```

**Update**:

It's unclear what you mean by wanting the width of the div to be dynamic and yet be multi-line.  At what point will the content wrap, or are you wanting to only do manual line breaks?  If you're doing content wrapping, would the div stick to 100% once it has to wrap?  If you don't want the width at 100%, what should its maximum width be set to?

You mentioned that you wanted the content left-aligned, yet if it's contained in a centered block that automatically sizes to fit, then you're basically asking for a centered inline element.  If you want the content to wrap to multiple lines and be left-aligned, you'll either have to specify a width or be fine with 100% width.  If you're wanting the lines of text to auto-balance and then to have the container resize to fit, I believe you're out of luck as far as what CSS offers.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to say that the pixel width of the `div` is not known in advance: it should become as wide as needed.

Comment: Then you can't center it since without specified width they'll be 100% wide - taking up the entire available space, and therefore "centered". You can specify left/right margins/padding to be of a certain thickness if that's what you want. Instead of `auto` put particular px, or em.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="showtitle">Centered div<br>with left-aligned text</div>
```

with

```
.showtitle {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: ...;
}
```

should work fine in Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to say that the pixel width of the `div` is not known in advance: it should become as wide as needed.

Answer (score 1):

I might be reading this wrong, but you should be able to just apply `margin: 0 auto; width:960px;` to your showtitle div and be golden.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to say that the pixel width of the `div` is not known in advance: it should become as wide as needed.

Comment: In that case, you can try `margin-left:50%;` but I'm not sure if this will suit your application

Answer (score 1):

```
<style>
    #outer {
        text-align: center;
    }
    #inner {
        display: -moz-inline-box; /* Firefox < 3 */
        display: inline-block; /* Standards */
        /* IE < 8, inline + hasLayout */
        *display: inline;
        *zoom: 1;
        text-align: left;
    }
</style>
<div id="outer"><div id="inner">Your centered content here</div></div>
```

Comment: This doesn't answer my question, because (see in the question) I'm only looking for a solution which doesn't need an inner <div>.

Comment: @pts, so you accepted "no solution"? Your question seems to explain the problem with nested `<div>`s as a problem with side-effects of `display: table`, not with the nested `<div>`s in general (which you clearly tried and were willing to accept up to that point). So you have access to the markup, and you've tried nested `<div>`s. Does my solution work, or does it fail in some way? Edit: Ack, sorry about the formatting. SO's pseudo-Markdown in comments seems to have some issues.

Comment: Your solution works (i.e. centers the `div`) in my Firefox 3.6, but your solution doesn't answer my question, because in my question I was asking for a solution without nested `div`s.

Comment: @pts, I understand that, but given that you've tried nested `<div>`s, isn't it merely an academic restriction rather than a practical one? The solution works and there isn't an obvious reason why you're adding that restriction.

Comment: In some cases such as mine it's inconvenient or cumbersome to change the DOM just to do style changes. If you usually don't encounter such cases, think of it as as academic restriction. +1ed it anyway.